# PL/SQL Infinite Loop

Tags: oracle, plsql

My PL/SQL skills are very limited so I apologize if this is a no brainer.  Basically, I have a loop that iterates through a clob.  The loop has given me problems in the past (infinite loop) when the value of the clob is null.  I tried to build some checks into the code for this loop, however my efforts to prevent an infinite loop fail.

**Here are the relevant pieces of the code:**

```
        v_offset        NUMBER DEFAULT 1;
        v_response      CLOB;

        SELECT VALUE
         INTO v_response
         FROM json_cache
        WHERE json_key = 'EMPLOYEES';

       --infinite loop occurs when v_response = ''
       LOOP
          EXIT WHEN v_offset > DBMS_LOB.getlength (v_response) 
              or DBMS_LOB.getlength (v_response) = 0 
              or v_offset = 400000;
          HTP.prn (DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR (v_response, 20000, v_offset));
          v_offset := v_offset + 20000;
       END LOOP;
```

Shouldn't the additional conditions in the `EXIT WHEN` statement prevent an infinite loop from occurring?  How do I terminate/prevent this loop when `v_response` is empty?  I would like to avoid wrapping this loop in an if statement and would prefer a guard in the loop.

Comment: I'm a bit rusty on my plsql, but if you set the default from offset to 1, wouldn't it count 1, 20001, 40001, etc. in the loop?

Comment: @sekky Yes it would, but wouldn't it consider the other two conditionals? `DBMS_LOB.getlength (v_response) = 0 or v_offset = 400000` and eventually stop the loop?

Comment: Then v_offset = 400000 won't satisfy. You can use either v_offset = 400001 or v_offset > 400000

Comment: @dcp1986 Wow, that was a bonehead move on my part.  Why doesn't the second conditional, `DBMS_LOB.getlength (v_response) = 0` stop the loop right away?

Comment: Because `DBMS_LOB.getlength (v_response)`returns `null` if `v_response` is `null` and any comparison with `null` evaluates to false.

Comment: You have to change the condition to DBMS_LOB.getlength (v_response) IS NOT NULL since DBMS_LOB.getlength will return null when v_response is null

Comment: @KlasLindbäck I appreciate the help but are you sure.  The following:  `declare
  v_response clob;
begin
   select value into v_response from json_cache where json_key = 'EMPLOYEES';
   dbms_output.put_line(v_response);
   dbms_output.put_line(dbms_lob.getlength(v_response)); 
end;
` outputs 0 to the console.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck I apologize you were right, oracle documentation states, `All functions in DBMS_LOB return NULL if any of the input parameters are NULL. All procedures in DBMS_LOB raise an exception if the LOB locator is input as NULL.`  My test was faulty.

Comment: @Kevin Null and zero-length are different values for a clob (unlike varchar2).

Answer (score 3):

You can always check for a null value:

```
loop
   exit when v_offset > dbms_lob.getlength (v_response) 
       or dbms_lob.getlength (v_response) = 0
       or v_offset = 400000
       or dbms_lob.getlength (v_response) is null; 
   v_offset := v_offset + 20000;
end loop;
```

Comment: And initialize v_offset to 0 instead of 1

Answer (score 1):

You can add additional control at the end like this;

```
DECLARE
    v_offset        NUMBER DEFAULT 1;
    v_response      CLOB;
BEGIN
    SELECT VALUE
     INTO v_response
     FROM json_cache
     WHERE json_key = 'EMPLOYEES';

   --infinite loop occurs when v_response = ''
   LOOP
      EXIT WHEN v_offset > DBMS_LOB.getlength (v_response) 
          or DBMS_LOB.getlength (v_response) = 0 
          or v_offset = 400000;
      HTP.prn (DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR (v_response, 20000, v_offset));
      v_offset := v_offset + 20000;

      if v_response is null then
         exit;
      end if;
   END LOOP;
END;
```